# What is the greatest divisor of $a^2-1$ set?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Given natural number $b>3$, what is the largest divisor of $\{a^2-1\,|\,a\ge b,2\nmid a, 3\nmid a\}$?

Since $3\mid (a-1)a(a+1)$ but $3\nmid a$, $3|(a^2-1)$. As $a$ is odd, both $a-1$ and $a+1$ are even, then $(a-1)(a+1)=(2k)(2k+2)$ for some natural number $k$. One of $k$ and $k+1$ is even. So $8|(a^2-1)$. $3$ and $8$ are coprime, $24|(a^2-1)$. But is $24$ the greatest divisor for any $b$?

Comment: For clarification: are you trying to find, essentially, the GCD of all possible $a^2+1$, for a given $b$? If so, I believe $24$ is your answer for any $b$, given that in the set, all $a = 6k \pm 1$ for some $k$. For these numbers, $24 \mid a^2 + 1$ for all $a$, but the quotients $(a^2-1)/24$ are the generalized pentagonal numbers, which don't share any common factors among all of them.

Comment: The answer to your question is affirmative. Could you please prove your last statement or give a reference thereto? By the way, your 2+1 is a typo and you rather mean 2−1, right?

Comment: I did mean $a^2 - 1$, yes. Proof may require longer than a comment, let me see.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer has been edited for clarity and removal of some unnecessary portions.

---

The problem can be stated restated as:

Given the set $A = \{a^2-1 \in \mathbb{N} \mid a = 6k \pm 1, a>b\}$, show that for any $b \in \mathbb{N}$, $24$ is the greatest common divisor of all elements in the set.

Define the sets $A^{\circ} = \{a \in \mathbb{N}, a = 6k \pm 1, a>b\}$ and $A' = \{\frac{1}{24}(a^2-1) \mid a \in A^{\circ}\}$.

Proof is in three steps:

- [A] Show that every member of $A$ is divisible by $24$
- [B]  Show that $\forall p \in \mathbb{P}, p > 2b+1$ there is at least one element of $A'$ for which $p \mid a'_i$.
- [C] Show that $\forall p \in \mathbb{P}, p > 2b+1$, there is at least of element of $A'$ for which $p \nmid a'_i$

---

*Theorem A*: Every member of $A$ is divisible by $24$

Proof:

$$a=6k \pm1 \implies a^2-1=36k^2 \pm 12k \tag1$$

Since $k$ is either even ($k=2m$) or odd ($k=2m+1$), we can expand equation $(1)$ into two different forms:

$$
a^2-1 =
\begin{cases}
144m^2 \pm 24m & k \text{ even} \tag2\\
144m^2+144m+36 \pm (24m + 12) & k \text{ odd}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Each of the expressions in $(2)$ is obviously divisible by 24.

---

*Theorem B*: $(\forall p \in \mathbb{P}, p>2b+1)(\exists a' \in A' : p \mid a')$

Proof: For all $p \ge 5$, we know that $p = 6k \pm 1$ for some $k$, so all $p \ge 5$ are elements of $A^{\circ}$. Given any $p$, one of $2p \pm 1$ is also an element of the set, depending on sign as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
2(6k + 1) - 1 & = 12k + 1 = 6(2k)+1 \tag{3a}\\
2(6k - 1) + 1 & = 12k - 1 = 6(2k) - 1 \tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$

From these, we can see that:

$$a = 2p + 1, p = 6k - 1 \implies a = 12k-1 \implies \\
a^2-1 = 144k^2-24k = 24(6k^2-k) = 24k(6k-1) = 24kp \tag4$$

$$a = 2p-1, p=6k+1 \implies a = 12k +1 \implies \\
a^2 - 1 = 144k^2+24k = 24(6k^2+k) = 24k(6k-1) = 24kp \tag5$$

For every prime $p \ge 5$, there must be an $a = 2p \pm 1$. Therefore, each prime $p > 2b+1$ is a factor of at least one element of $A'$, and hence each is a factor at least one element of $A$.

---

*Theorem C*: $(\forall p \in \mathbb{P}, p>2b+1)(\exists a' \in A' : p \nmid a')$

Proof: Consider $a'_q, a'_r \in A'$ derived from two consecutive values of $k$. We have:

$$a_q = (6k+1)^2 - 1 = 36k^2 + 12k = 12k\left(3k+1\right)\\
a_r = (6(k+1)+1)^2 - 1 = 36k^2 + 84k = 12k\left(3k+7\right)$$

If $k$ is odd, then $i = 3k+1$ and $j = 3k+7$ are both even. Neither $\frac{i}{2}$ nor $\frac{j}{2}$ is divisible by $3$, but $\frac{j}{2}-\frac{i}{2} = 3$. Therefore $(\frac{j}{2}, \frac{i}{2}) = 1$, and any given prime can divide exactly one of them.

If $k$ is even, then $i$ and $j$ are consecutive members of the arithmetic progression $6z+1$, and are therefore coprime.

Taking the odd and even cases together, for any value of $k$, and any prime $p \ge 5$, at least one of $a_q$ and $a_r$ is indivisible by $p$. The same must be true of $24a_q$ and $24a_r$, and therefore no prime $p \ge 2b+1$ divides all elements of $A$.

---

Theorem A establishes that all elements of $A$ are divisible by $24$.

Theorem B establishes that every prime $p \ge 2b+1$ is a divisor of at least one element of $A$.

Theorem C establishes that every prime $p \ge 2b+1$ is *not* a divisor of at least one element of $A$.

Therefore each element of $A$ is coprime to at least one other element of $A$, and the greatest divisor of all elements of $A$ must be $24$.

Comment: To add one more step, you are saying I can pick arbitrarily large two distinct prime $k$'s such that $6−1$'s are both prime so thus produced two $(6−1)$'s are coprime. Is that right? it seems obvious but how do I prove for infinitely many prime $$'s are prime? The purpose of this setup is to produce infinitely many coprime $k(6k-1)$ pairs.

Comment: Well, there's a difference between "coprime" and "shares no common factor with **all** elements of the set $\{a^2-1 \mid a\ge 3, a=6k - 1\}$." But if we're looking *only* at the $6k-1$ integers (or only the primes in that progression, we might have an easier time of it. Is the *real* question here actually "How can I generate infinitely many coprime pairs of the form $k(6k-1)$?" Edited addition: you likely cannot pick arbitrary primes for $k$, since $6k-1$ isn't always prime. But you could pick primes of the form $6k-1$ and, if the values of $k$ are coprime, the values of $6k-1$ are coprime.

Comment: But note, we would need a pair of coprime integers $k_1,k_2$ such that $p_i=6k_i -1$ is prime, and $q_i=2p+1$ is also prime. I think there might be other constraints as well. I guess again my question of whether we're looking at $k(6k-1)$ or $a^2-1$ is salient.

Comment: I think my question is quite clear that it asks for $a>b$ for any given positive integer $b$. So I want to show that all elements of the set $\{\frac{a^2-1}{24}|a>b\}$ has only $1$ as the (largest) common divisor. Your answer has not proved that yet. It suffices to show there are infinitely many coprime pairs in the form of $(j(6j-1), k(6k-1))$ for positive integers $j<k$.

Comment: Hmm. I think we're talking across one another here? Our set is $A=\{(a^2-1)\mid a\equiv \pm 1\pmod 6,a>b\}$, and we want to show that this set shares no common divisors $d>24$. If somehow that's not the intent, tell me. My proof of that was: [A] $24$ divides all members of the set; [B] Every member of $A$, when divided by $24$, is a generalized pentagonal number of the form $\frac12(3m^2\pm m)$; [C] Every prime is a factor of at least one member of $A$, so $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\cdots) = 1$, hence the full set has no common factor $d>24$. This holds for $b=3$, therefore it holds for all $b$.

Comment: Specifically, the set $A$ is infinite no matter the value of $b$, and the infinite members of the set cannot all have a common divisor $d>24$, because every prime $p>2b\pm 1$ (the sign depends on $b$) is a divisor of at least one of the member of $A$. EDIT: going to edit the proof above to be a bit more clear.

Comment: We agree on the intent. I agree that every prime is a factor of at least one member of $\frac A{24}$ the element of which is of the form $k(6k\pm 1)$. For any given prime, we can choose $k$ to be a multiple of that prime or just that prime if it is large enough. Right? However, $k$ being prime does not imply $6k-1$ is prime. I do not see how this arrives at GCD$(A/24) =1$. I do not see why "This holds for $b=3$ therefore it holds for all $b$." It is wrong to claim a positive integer sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ has $1$ as the GCD, then $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ has $1$ as its GCD.

Comment: Take a look at the clarified proof. The claim is not $\gcd((a_n)^{\infty}_n=1) =1 \implies \gcd((a_n)^{\infty}_{n=m})=1$. The claim proven is that $\forall m, \gcd((a_n)^{\infty}_{n=m})=1$, with no dependence on separate values of $m$. (Proven by showing that *all* primes above $2b+1$ are a divisor of at least one $a_n$, but not a divisor of *all* $a_n$.)